# Windows IoT + BME280

Tags: windows-10-iot-core, adafruit

I'm trying to use the BME280 Sensor, but it won't work. I'm using this sample from https://www.hackster.io/windows-iot/weather-station-67e40d and https://www.hackster.io/23021/weather-station-v-3-0-b8b8bc

But in both cases I can't find the sensor. When I boot the Raspberry OS and use there a python script, I'm able to read everything.

Currently I'm running Windows 10.0.15063.0

Currently my App is runnning on the BMP280 Sensor this works, but when I replace it by the BME it won't.

Comment: Have you test the [sample code](https://www.hackster.io/windows-iot/weather-station-v-2-0-8abe16#code) Lesson_203V2 for BME280? What's error you encountered?

Comment: Jep,  
bme280 = await I2cDevice.FromIdAsync(dis[0].Id, settings);
Returns null

Comment: I wonder how your BMP280 works? Above line returns not null?

Comment: I tried the same configuration (wiring and everything) but with the raspberry os and using this pyhton https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_BME280

and it returns on address 77 the sensor

Comment: But `I2cDevice.FromIdAsync` should always returns a I2C device whatever you connected to, BMP or BME or other I2C devices. You can use this [command tool](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/i2ctesttool) to do some test.

Comment: I'm not able to build this tool,

`2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include\agile.h(16): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'wrl\client.h': No such file or directory`
What additional packages do I need to install? I found this issue, but no solution https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/issues/474

Comment: Ok on an old VM I could build it (this had VS 2015 and the full Win 8 SDK installed) 

but there is no change, I could't find the sensor on the address 0x77
`[192.168.0.155]: PS C:\Data\Users\System\Documents> .\I2cTestTool.exe 0x77 I2C1
  Type 'help' for a list of commands
>
[192.168.0.155]: PS C:\Data\Users\System\Documents> .\I2cTestTool.exe 77 I2C1
  Type 'help' for a list of commands
>
[192.168.0.155]: PS C:\Data\Users\System\Documents>
`

Comment: Do some test using [this sample](https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/I2CAccelerometer/CS). Remember replace the address with yours.

Comment: Damn my fault, I used yesterday the powershell. But there is no input possible. Now I used SSH/Putty and I can connect to the sensor and it respond to me.

thanks your sample works for me (I don't know why the original code isn't working)
I will now rewrite the code and than hope that everything is working :-)

Comment: Perfect I don't know the differences but now everything works. 

Thank you :-)